# pip raises stdio.h not found error on Mac OS X Mavericks (10.9)

Tags: python, macos, gcc, numpy, mysql-python

I have tried countless solutions at this point and nothing seems to work. I'm trying to install mysql-python, but this happens with numpy and other packages requiring gcc as well:

```
building '_mysql' extension

gcc-4.2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 -I/usr/local/mysql/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/_mysql.o -Os -g -fno-strict-aliasing -arch x86_64

In file included from _mysql.c:29:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:33:10: fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found

#include <stdio.h>

         ^

1 error generated.

error: command 'gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1
```

To point:

I have installed command line tools

Added symlink from /usr/bin/gcc to /usr/bin/gcc-4.2

```
gcc-4.2 --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0
Thread model: posix
```

Created a dummy c file, successfully compiled, and ran it, so gcc itself is fine

```
$ cat a.c
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    printf("hello\n");
}

$ gcc-4.2 a.c
a.c:3:1: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
main()
^~~~
1 warning generated.

$ ./a.out
hello
```

And for good measure,

```
$ xcode-select -p
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

What is going on?!

**EDIT** - Forgot to include python version

```
$ python
Python 2.7.2 (v2.7.2:8527427914a2, Jun 11 2011, 15:22:34)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
```

**EDIT** - Exciting development. Setting these variables makes some progress:

```
$ export CFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64"
$ export FFLAGS="-m32 -m64"
$ export LDFLAGS="-Wall -undefined dynamic_lookup -bundle -arch i386 -arch x86_64"
$ export CC=gcc-4.2
$ export CXX="g++ -arch i386 -arch x86_64"
```

However it fails again at

```
gcc-4.2 -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -g -Wall -undefined dynamic_lookup -bundle build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/_mysql.o -L/usr/local/mysql/lib -lmysqlclient_r -o build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/_mysql.so -arch x86_64

ld: library not found for -lSystem

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

error: command 'gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1
```

I suspect it's a similar error having to do with command tools. Also, why is it using "/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk" ? (excuse the noob questions, I'm trying to migrate from vim/unix to pycharm/mac and it's not going very well so far :( )

Comment: Is there a reason you're using 2.7.2? I thought 10.9 shipped with 2.7.4.? Did you brew install python?

Comment: I upgraded from Snow Leopard, I guess Mavericks didn't actually upgrade Python? I haven't installed it manually.

Comment: I would try installing brew. And then doing a brew install python. It'll install pip. It'll also tell you if your command line tools are out of date and help you out with that. Hopefully it'll make things less rocky on OS X.

Comment: @wegry I was so frustrated with this I just abandoned it for the time being, but I just gave it another try and THIS WORKED. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @wegry mentioned above--

```
brew install python
```

confirming with

```
$ which python
/usr/local/homebrew/bin/python
```

just made this entirely go away. Successfully installed numpy and mysql-python with pip!

Comment: I guess I did some changes in the toolchains (the way they are handled through xcode is a big mess....), and a `brew upgrade python` did the trick for me! I guess it picked the new path that was set since the 1st installation of python..

Answer (score 15):

Starting from Mojave `xcode-select --install` is not enough, you should also install the package that can be found at `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg`. Source: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/104296

Comment: This also worked for me, I wonder why it's an optional install now?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
xcode-select --install
```